# Another exception was thrown: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:/// for network image

Tags: flutter

I have saved an image link into my firebase and the link is workable to show the image, however, when I insert the link to the `NetworkImage` in such:

```
Image(
  height: 80,
  width: 80,
  image: NetworkImage(shopLogo),
  fit: BoxFit.contain),
),
```

there is an error `Another exception was thrown: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///` when I enter this page but if I hot reload the page, the image only able to load. Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: *"Anyone know how to solve this?"*, `NetworkImage` does not accept local files (only `http://` / `https://` uris are supported)

Comment: @pskink the shopLogo that i mentioned is a url "https://....."

Comment: what do you see if you `print('shopLogo: $shopLogo')`? what are the top 5-10 frames of the stacktrace when the exception is thrown?

Comment: i got this when i print the shopLogo ```The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI
file:///firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/grocerex.appspot.com/o/image_picker8401035419565080210.jpg?alt=media&token=305d4ff6-7072-4334-
abf9-472c57191638``` however, this is my shopLogo demo image link https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/grocerex.appspot.com/o/image_picker8401035419565080210.jpg?alt=media&token=305d4ff6-7072-4334-abf9-472c57191638

Comment: @pskink but if i hot reload it, then the images will suddenly just appear without error

Comment: what do you see on the logs if you call `print('shopLogo: $shopLogo')` inside `build` method?

Comment: when i first navigate to the page, the statement I print shows this ```shopLogo: ``` but after I hot reload the page, the print shows this ```shopLogo: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/grocerex.appspot.com/o/image_picker8401035419565080210.jpg?alt=media&token=305d4ff6-7072-4334-abf9-472c57191638```

Comment: so you need to use `FutureBuilder` - it seems that you are getting your link from some `async` source that returns a `Future` - thats why you need a `FutureBuilder`

Comment: homaigod @pskink THANKS FOR YOUR SUGGESTION, I searched it up on how to implement the futurebuilder and it works after all, tq so much!!

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkImage` is for image files on the internet

`Image.file` is for image files on the device (local)

```
Image.file(
  File('PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE'),
  height: 80,
  width: 80,
  fit: BoxFit.contain,
)
```

Ensure necessary permissions to use this

Comment: The shopLogo that I insert in the NetworkImage is actually an url return from firebase

Answer (score -1):

For **Firebase Hosted Files** with links like `file:///firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...`, replace the `file:///` with `https://` to use in a `NetworkImage`

So your code should be

```
Image(
  height: 80,
  width: 80,
  image: NetworkImage(shopLogo.replaceFirst("file:///", "https://")),
  fit: BoxFit.contain),
),
```